# How to give a specified space for a content before loading using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I display ads on my site but to prevent invalid clicks I want to try adding a space below ads (the ad is 280px high) and the space below I tried or would be is 280px high too so even if the page is still loading or the ad havent loaded yet, the space would be there and once the ad is loaded it would only occupy that space area only.

I tried doing this;

```
<div class="mt16 mb24" style="z-index: 1;">
        <div style="padding: 140px 0 140px 0; z-index: -1; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                <!-- AD START -->
                bla bla ad code here
                <!-- AD END -->
        </div>
        <h4 class="mt0 mb0 text-uppercase">Sponsored AD</h4>
</div>
```

But it didn't work. Instead it added padding at the top and the bottom of the ad. It would be appreciated if you could point out what I'm doing wrong here. (I could have made something using a javascript but I don't actually know java)

Comment: Setting the `height` and/or `width` of an element controls the size of the content area on that element.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Scott Marcus (https://stackoverflow.com/users/695364/scott-marcus) for this answer. 
"Setting the height and/or width of an element controls the size of the content area on that element"
I did thought of using it but nah I decided to ask for help instead but it worked!
Here is the new code:

```
<div class="mt16 mb24">
<div style="height: 300px; min-height: 250px; max-height: 400px;">
    <!-- AD START -->
    ad codes here
    <!-- AD END -->
</div>
<h4 class="mt0 mb0 text-uppercase">Sponsored AD</h4>
```

Comment: it's OK to post your own answer and accept it. Just make sure to post your solution in the answer. it will help other users that may be searching for the same question. Just edit this Answer to include your code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but it simulates attempting to load an image after the dom is ready, with the placeholder frame for the ad already in place on the page before the ad actually loads.. (granted, the img won't load due to cors on SO)

```js
function loadAd() {
  var url = "http://image.prntscr.com/image/AG29sCCYS2_jPBlZxYuQ9g.png";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("ad1").src = url;
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
#ad-space {
  padding: 140px 0 140px 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 280px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadAd()">
  <div class="mt16 mb24" style="z-index: 1;">
    <div id="ad-space">
      <img id="ad1">
      <!-- AD END -->
    </div>
    <h4 class="mt0 mb0 text-uppercase">Sponsored AD</h4>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus - via URL, or do you mean via an actual upload? I must be missing something. Thanks!

Comment: Via URL. Just don't set the HTML source by building and HTML string. Set the `.src` property of DOM image element. I have edited your answer to include this.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I see what you mean. Thought about doing it that way with the img element already in the dom, but was trying to simulate more of an ad actually loading outside the dom, but yeah, that makes more sense. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Even if the ad were to load outside of the DOM, you can still do this. You would just create a new `<img>` element via `var i = new Image()` and then set the `src` property and then finally inject that element into the DOM without having to have a static `<img>` element sitting  there.

Comment: True true. Course I know we went above what the OP was originally asking, since it seemed to be more of a CSS issue anyways lol. Thanks again for the assistance! Have a good one.